# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'bash' found among steps

Tags: linux, bash, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to run bash commands throw Jenkins pipeline, I'm calling a function that has some bash commands but I'm getting this error:

> ```
>  java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'bash' found among steps
> ```

This is the function:

> def copy_tools(){
>
> ```
>    // tools
>    bash '''#!/bin/bash
>    mkdir X6//CX6
>    cp ${x6_tools_path} .
>    unzip CX6.zip -d .\\X6
>    '''
> ```
>
> }

can you please help?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You want to use `sh`, not `bash`. You aren't directly running bash in your code. You need to run the `sh` pipeline step, which will run the configured shell.

```
def copy_tools(){

   // tools
   sh '''#!/bin/bash
   mkdir X6//CX6
   cp ${x6_tools_path} .
   unzip CX6.zip -d .\\X6
   '''
}
```